# How could I Design a layout background like this in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I am looking for a design which look like a wave shape paint. I don't want to use any images. I want to do it by programmatically.

I read a lots of articles and others answers but non of them fulfill my requirement.

I have to achieve such kind of background design in flutter.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can achieve such kind of design using `Clippath` widget in flutter.

Step 1: First create a new dart file named **my_clipper.dart** and paste below code in **my_clipper.dart** file:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    class MyClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
      @override
      Path getClip(Size size) {
        var path = Path();
        path.lineTo(0, 220);
        path.quadraticBezierTo(
            size.width / 4, 160 /*180*/, size.width / 2, 175);
        path.quadraticBezierTo(
            3 / 4 * size.width, 190, size.width, 130);
        path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
        path.close();
        return path;
      }

      @override
      bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
        return false;
      }
    }
```

Step 2: Now in your Scaffold or in any other widget use the `MyCLipper` Class like this:

```
     home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            ClipPath(
              clipper: MyClipper(),
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.white,
              )
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
```